# SignaturePad package for MAUI

Tags: c#, .net-maui

There's a [Xamarin package](https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad) to implement signing feature in a Xamarin application. For now this repository is archived and there's no .net6.0 implementation for MAUI.

I tried to find a substitute for this package but did not succeed. Unfortunately commercial packages are not an option for my case.

Maybe I am missing something and MAUI has a such package?

Comment: Since you have the code, why not look at it and translate to MAUI, perhaps even upload it to github so others can benefit

Comment: You're right, I am working on porting Xamarin code to MAUI, but there are issues. That will be separate question regarding these issues.

Comment: You can also checkout my library it has a Signature Pad and a bunch of other things  https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a package in maui called `Maui.CommunityToolkit`. You can use the `DrawingView` as a replacement.
You can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/drawingview).

In addition, I found a discussion about SignaturePad package for MAUI on git.
Here is the website: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/discussions/270?sort=new