# MAUI project and Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Resource

Tags: c#, xamarin, .net-maui

I am trying to port [Xamarin code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73775046/signaturepad-package-for-maui) to MAUI, and do not understand how to fix this issue:

In Xamarin project, there are calls:

```cs
Resource.Id.background_image
Resource.Id.caption
Resource.Styleable.SignaturePadView

etc etc etc
```

I have copied resources from the Xamarin project.

[image: Resources-Xamarin-MAUI]

And Xamarin project does not have other resources to transfer to MAUI project.

And In Xamarin project I can't inspect particular resources, names are displayed in grayed color and I can't ctrl+click to view them.

[image: Xamarin-Resource-References]

What I don't understand, how to deal with resource visibility issues:

[image: Resources-Are-Not-Visible]

Where are resources, related to `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Resource` namespace should be located in my case, and why they are not visible for my code?

=====
UPDATE

I have tried to set "Embedded resource" and "Resource" in properties of files in the `Resources` folder, but without success.

====
UPDATE #2

I decided to use DrawingView from Maui.CommunityToolkit to create the same functionality. It will take less time than porting Xamarin.SignaturePad to MAUI.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/drawingview

How to use DrawingView: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7rw13_a5GR0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to migrate your project, you need to update any incompatible NuGet packages. Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad is not compatible in MAUI, you need to update this NuGet package. You can check [this doc](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Migrating-from-Xamarin.Forms-(Preview)) for changes in properties of files after Android migration.

Comment: Thank you. Sure, I avoid to use Xamarin packages, and replace Xamarin classes/namespaces usage to MAUI classes/namespaces usage. But porting Xamarin.SignaturePad takes to much time. I will create necessary functionality using Maui DrawingView control. Thanks again.